# Employing Pyspark How to determine the frequency of each event and its event-by-event frequency

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset like:

Data

```
a
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
a
a
b
```

I would like to include a column that like the one below. The data will be in the form of a1,1 in the column, where the first element represents the event frequency (a1), or how often "a" appears in the field, and the second element (,1) is the frequency for each event, or how often "a" repeats before any other element (b) in the field. Can we carry this out with PySpark?

```
Data   Frequency
     a        a1,1
     a        a1,2    
     a        a1,3
     a        a1,4
     a        a1,5
     b        b1,1
     b        b1,2
     b        b1,3
     a        a2,1
     a        a2,2
     b        b2,1
```

Comment: This is unclear. What is the difference between the *event frequency* and the *frequency for each event*?? How do you get from `a` to `a1`? Please edit your question to add this info.

Comment: Actually, I would like to include a column that like the one below. The data will be in the form of a1,1 in the column, where the first element represents the event frequency (a1), or how often "a" appears in the field, and the second element (,1) is the frequency for each event, or how often "a" repeats before any other element (b) in the field. Can we carry this out with PySpark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result by doing this,

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 'string').toDF("Data")

print("Original Data:")
df.show()

print("Result:")
df.withColumn("ID", F.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
    .withColumn("group",
            F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("ID"))
            - F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("Data").orderBy("ID"))
    ) \
    .withColumn("element_freq", F.when(F.col('Data') != 'abcd', F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("ID"))).otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
    .withColumn("event_freq", F.when(F.col('Data') != 'abcd', F.dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("Data").orderBy("group"))).otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
    .withColumn("Frequency", F.concat_ws(',', F.concat(F.col("Data"), F.col("event_freq")), F.col("element_freq"))) \
    .orderBy("ID")\
    .drop("ID", "group", "event_freq", "element_freq")\
    .show()
```

```
Original Data:
+----+
|Data|
+----+
|   a|
|   a|
|   a|
|   a|
|   a|
|   b|
|   b|
|   b|
|   a|
|   a|
|   b|
+----+

Result:
+----+---------+
|Data|Frequency|
+----+---------+
|   a|     a1,1|
|   a|     a1,2|
|   a|     a1,3|
|   a|     a1,4|
|   a|     a1,5|
|   b|     b1,1|
|   b|     b1,2|
|   b|     b1,3|
|   a|     a2,1|
|   a|     a2,2|
|   b|     b2,1|
+----+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Window functions. I give you to options just in case

**Option 1, separating groups and Frequency**

```
        #Variable to use in the groupby
k=Window.partitionBy().orderBy('index')

(
  
  #Create an index of df to order by
  df1.withColumn('index', monotonically_increasing_id())
  
  #Create a column that puts a consecutive and previous Data in a row   
  .withColumn('group', lag('Data').over(k))
 
#  #Where consecutive and previous dont match, conditionally assign a 1 else o
 .withColumn('group', when(col('data')!=col('group'),1).otherwise(0))
  
   # Concat Data and sum of outcome from above per group and ordered by index  
  .withColumn('group', concat('Data',sum('group').over(Window.partitionBy('Data').orderBy('index'))+1))
  
  #rank outcome above in the order in which they appeared in initial df
.withColumn('Frequency', rank().over(Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('index')))

).sort('index').drop('index').show(truncate=False)


+----+-----+---------+
|Data|group|Frequency|
+----+-----+---------+
|a   |a1   |1        |
|a   |a1   |2        |
|a   |a1   |3        |
|a   |a1   |4        |
|a   |a1   |5        |
|b   |b2   |1        |
|b   |b2   |2        |
|b   |b2   |3        |
|a   |a2   |1        |
|a   |a2   |2        |
|b   |b3   |1        |
+----+-----+---------+
```

**Option 2 gives an output you wanted**

```
#Variable to use in the groupby
k=Window.partitionBy().orderBy('index')

(
  
  #Create an index of df to order by
  df1.withColumn('index', monotonically_increasing_id())
  
  #Create a column that puts a consecutive and previous Data in a row   
  .withColumn('Frequency', lag('Data').over(k))
 
#  #Where consecutive and previous dont match, conditionally assign a 1 else o
 .withColumn('Frequency', when(col('data')!=col('Frequency'),1).otherwise(0))
  
   # Concat Data and sum of outcome from above per group and ordered by index  
  .withColumn('Frequency', concat('Data',sum('Frequency').over(Window.partitionBy('Data').orderBy('index'))+1))
  
  #rank outcome above in the order in which they appeared in initial df
.withColumn('Frequency', array_join(array('Frequency',rank().over(Window.partitionBy('Frequency').orderBy('index'))),','))

).sort('index').drop('index').show(truncate=False)


+----+---------+
|Data|Frequency|
+----+---------+
|a   |a1,1     |
|a   |a1,2     |
|a   |a1,3     |
|a   |a1,4     |
|a   |a1,5     |
|b   |b2,1     |
|b   |b2,2     |
|b   |b2,3     |
|a   |a2,1     |
|a   |a2,2     |
|b   |b3,1     |
+----+---------+
```

Comment: You can do Window.orderBy('index') directly, no need to the extra empty .partitionBy()